# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference crear pdf desde imagen

Tags: java, android

El problema es que no logro que cuando presiono el botón convertir me genere el pdf, me da como que esta nulo en:

**Error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>               Process: com.thebitles.smartlibreaderpdf, PID: 25998
>               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
>                   at com.thebitles.smartlibreaderpdf.EscaneoImagePdf_Fragment.createPdf(EscaneoImagePdf_Fragment.java:275)
>                   at com.thebitles.smartlibreaderpdf.EscaneoImagePdf_Fragment.onClick(EscaneoImagePdf_Fragment.java:262)

```
public EscaneoImagePdf_Fragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
```

**Método oncreate del fragment**

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (!checkPermission()) {
                openActivity();
            } else {
                if (checkPermission()) {
                    requestPermissionAndContinue();
                } else {
                    openActivity();
                }
            }
            //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), EscaneoDocumentos.class);
            //getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Método donde creo la vista y cargo datos a utilizar**

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container ,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escaneo_imagepdf_, container, false);

            //ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.IVImageescaneodocumentos);

            //image.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagetopdf);


            StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
            StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

            boton_seleccion = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.idseleccionarImagen);
            boton_convertir = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Idconvertirapdf);
            iv_image  = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.IVImageescaneodocumentos);



            boton_seleccion.setOnClickListener(this);
            boton_convertir.setOnClickListener(this);


            fn_permission();


            return view;

        }
```

**Método para los permisos necesarios de la aplicación**

```
        private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
        private boolean checkPermission() {

            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ;
        }

        private void requestPermissionAndContinue() {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.permission_necessary));
                    alertBuilder.setMessage(R.string.storage_permission_is_encessary_to_wrote_event);
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                    , READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();
                    Log.e("", "permission denied, show dialog");
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            } else {
                openActivity();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

            if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (permissions.length > 0 && grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean flag = true;
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag) {
                        openActivity();
                    } else {
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }

                } else {
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            } else {
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }
        }

        private void openActivity() {
            //add your further process after giving permission or to download images from remote server.
        }



        /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
        public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void init() {

        }

        private void listener() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.idseleccionarImagen:
                    new MaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .title("Seleccione de donde tomar la imagen")
                            .items(R.array.uploadImages)
                            .itemsIds(R.array.itemIds)
                            .itemsCallback(new MaterialDialog.ListCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSelection(MaterialDialog dialog, View view, int which, CharSequence text) {
                                    switch (which){
                                        case 0:
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_PICTURE);
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            genRandom();
                                            Intent intent2 = new Intent(
                                                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                            _imagefileUri = Uri.fromFile(getFile());

                                            intent2.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT , _imagefileUri);
                                            startActivityForResult(intent2, CAPTURE_PHOTO);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                            .show();
                    break;

                case R.id.Idconvertirapdf:
                    if (boolean_save){

                        Intent intent1=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),EscaneoDocumentos.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);

                    }else {
                        createPdf();
                    }
                    break;


            }
        }
```

**Método que crea el PDF donde me da en la linea el error mencionado arriba**

```
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        private void createPdf(){

            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
            PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 1).create();
            PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

            Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0 , null);
            document.finishPage(page);


        // GRABAR LA IMAGEN

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SMART LIBRARY PDF");

        if (!root.exists()){

            root.mkdir();
        }

        File file = new File(root, "PruebaPDFsMART.PDF");
        try {

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            document.writeTo(fileOutputStream);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "El error es: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } //ppal createpdf

        // close the document
        document.close();



    }


    public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
        try{
            byte [] encodeByte= Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
            return bitmap;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Actividad result**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!=null) {

            Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            assert selectedImageURI != null;
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImageURI, filePathColumn,null,null,null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();


            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String myruta = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myruta);
            iv_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




            boton_convertir.setClickable(true);

        }else if(requestCode == CAPTURE_PHOTO){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagefileUri.getPath());
                iv_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                boton_convertir.setClickable(true);

            }
        }
    }


    private void fn_permission() {
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) )  {

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{String.valueOf(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) , READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }

            if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA))) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);

            }
        } else {
            boolean_permission = true;


        }
    }



    private File getFile() {
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        file = new File(filepath, IMAGE_CAPTURE_FOLDER);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        System.out.println(filepath);
        return new File(file + File.separator + _imageFileName
                + ".jpg");
    }

    public void genRandom(){
        Random r = new Random();
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        final int N = 10;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            sb.append(alphabet.charAt(r.nextInt(alphabet.length())));
        }
        _imageFileName = sb.toString();

    }
```

**Mi graddle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thebitles.smartlibreaderpdf"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.emmanuelkehinde:shutdown:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.thebitles.smartlibreaderpdf">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" ></uses-permission>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" ></uses-permission>





    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"



    android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".BienvenidaActivity">
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            // La actividad para ver los pdf por ahora es la segunda en ejecutarse.
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".VerArchivosPDF" />


    <activity android:name=".EscaneoQR" />

        <activity android:name=".Salirapp" />

        <activity android:name=".EscaneoDocumentos" />







    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: El error es un poco obvio, comenta Cual es la imagen que tratas de agregar?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, en realidad quiero guardar la imagen que selecciono de la galeria o la que obtengo al tomar la foto con la camara, ambas me cargan bien en el textview. Tendre que volver a instanciar dentro de create pdf a la imagen??

Comment: El error es muy claro, cuando entras en la función `createPdf`, la variable `bitmap`, que no se donde la creas ni la seteas, está a `null`. Falta que publiques qué haces con esa variable antes de llegar a la función `createPdf`. Lo descubrirías fácilmente depurando.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad era algo obvio pero no lograba darme cuenta, aun no se usar el debug pero logre mirando paso a paso y el error era que no cargaba correctamente bitmap. Dejo el codigo como lo solucione. Ahora me convierte sin problemas a pdf, lo hace con la imagen con formato incorrecto pero es un gran paso. bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: Exacto @Eder debes obtener la imagen a partir de un path, crear el bitmap y posteriormente agregarlo a tu documento PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas obteniendo :

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference

porque tratas de llamar el método `getWidth()` en una instancia de Bitmap que tiene valor null. Debes obtener el Bitmap a partir de una ruta, de esta forma crearías el bitmap

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
```

de esta forma puedes agregarlo a un ImageView:

```
imagen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

e incluso a tu documento PDF

```
private void createPdf(){

    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 1).create();
    PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    canvas.drawPaint(paint);

    //bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath); 

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0 , null);
    document.finishPage(page);
    ...
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora pude resolver, lo único que al tomar la foto me carga al revés el en image view pero es otro tema a resolver. Gracias a todos.